# Dependency injection into HTML img src tag within an ng-repeat loop not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a strange issue with my a value not properly working. Basically I have a big array of id's that correspond to images on a server.

```
Images: {
    "Set1" : {
        'Blue':['8277','8278','8279','8280','8281','8282','8283'],
        'Green':['8284','8285'],
        'Red':['8286','8287','8288','8289']
    }
}
```

Within my controller model I have an `ng-repeat` that looks something like this.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in cities">
        <p> 
            <img src="http://wesbite.api.com/{{value[0]}}/half?system=xxxxml&pubtoken=hfdshfgsjkhgkhfkjghkdshgjkshfhdffhksfhgdfhgdskhsgkf4658cee&refreshRate=2000">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My issue that it will not actually resolve the img onto the page. If I pull in imgs any other way it works fine.

Is this a problem with mixing HTML and within an ng-repeat loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Documents : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

```
 <div ng-controller="myCtl">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in cities">
                <p> <img ng-src="http://wesbite.api.com/{{value[0]}}/half?system=xxxxml&pubtoken=hfdshfgsjkhgkhfkjghkdshgjkshfhdffhksfhgdfhgdskhsgkf4658cee&refreshRate=2000"></p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

use ng-src in place of just src

```
<img ng-src="http://wesbite.api.com/{{value[0]}}/half?system=xxxxml&pubtoken=hfdshfgsjkhgkhfkjghkdshgjkshfhdffhksfhgdfhgdskhsgkf4658cee&refreshRate=2000">
```